# RecyclerView with load more progressbar at bottom

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, onscrolllistener

### I tried implementing addOnScrollListener() but this thing fetch data and loading the recycler view from the beginning every time.i want to load the data after the current position.Here is my sample code

```
 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_load, null);

        progressBar = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        myClickHandler();

        business_rv = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.business_rv);
        business = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,false);
        business_rv.setHasFixedSize(true);
        business_rv.setLayoutManager(business);
        if (business_rv.getLayoutManager() instanceof LinearLayoutManager) {
            business = (LinearLayoutManager) business_rv.getLayoutManager();
            business_rv.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
                @Override
                public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                    super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
                    UpdateRecyclerView(url);
                }
            });
        }

        return view;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

what you need is endless recycler view ,which will load the data while scrolling . Here I have attached link for that implementation.

[Follow this link](http://android-pratap.blogspot.in/2015/06/endless-recyclerview-with-progress-bar.html)

Answer (score -2):

use this as

```
 _recycler.addOnScrollListener(_recyclerViewOnScrollListener);   

 private RecyclerView.OnScrollListener recyclerViewOnScrollListener = new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
                super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
            }

            @Override
            public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
                int visibleItemCount = layoutManager.getChildCount();
                int totalItemCount = layoutManager.getItemCount();
                int firstVisibleItemPosition = layoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();

                if (!isLoading && !isLastPage) {
                    if ((visibleItemCount + firstVisibleItemPosition) >= totalItemCount
                            && firstVisibleItemPosition >= 0
                            && totalItemCount >= PAGE_SIZE) {
                        loadMoreItems(++currentPage);
                    }
                }
            }
    };
```